# Creating New Wix Project In Visual Studio 2017 throws an error

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Installed it without any specific things selected like C++ development or Windows development etc. After that I have installed Wix through wixtoolset, which downloaded and installed wix tool set components. After that I have installed the Wix ToolSet extension for Visual Studio 2017. Restarted the Visual Studio and trying to create a new project through File -> New -> Project - WiX Toolset -> Setup Project.

It gives the error and does not let me create the project. I am totally new to WiX and have just a little knowledge about Visual Studio.

[image: VS17 Error]

Comment: Which version of wixtoolset did you install?

Comment: WiX Toolset v3.11.0.1528

Comment: Hmm Wix Toolset v3.11.x is compatible with VS 2017 and its extensions. So now the problem is with Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizardInterface.dll. The DLL is either missing on your computer, or it got corrupted somehow. Please confirm if the DLL is present. It can be found at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

Comment: You are correct. I don't have that DLL present at the location you mentioned. How should I download it and make it available to the VS17? But I do not get the point, why this DLL is not present or as you mentioned might get corrupt?

Comment: I'm not sure either why it's missing but I believe you can download/install it through Nuget Package Manager. Open VS, and load your solution file. Go to Tools --> Nuget Package Manager --> Package Manager Console. And then run this command: Install-Package VSSDK.TemplateWizardInterface.8

Comment: I want to try the given solution with Nuget Package Manager but I don't have the solution file at all since I was not able to create any solution from the scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141876/discussion-between-azaz-ul-haq-and-jaydeep-ranipa).

Comment: Azaz, I tried reinsalling the VS17 with .Net Dev environment and Windows Desktop Env. Now able to see the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I did not select any of the Installation workloads for VS17 and installed it just to make the installation faster.

Through the comments from Azaz, I came to know that NuGet Package Manager is required to install the packages on demand. But since I could not see the NuGet option at all, I tried to install it with Extensions and updates but it did not work. I did a bit of research and found that at least one .Net development workload is required at a time of VS17 installation which will make the NuGet install automatically in VS17.

So I uninstalled the VS17, WiX at all and removed them from the system. Then Installed VS17 with certain workload packages as shown in the below screenshot. 
[image: VS17 install screen]

After that I installed WiX and an extension for the same in VS17. i.e. Votive2017.vsix.

I restart the VS17 and now I am able to create project for WiX.

Looks like there is something I missed somewhere in installing which did not let me install required DLLs and GUID feature, which were important for creating project templates.

Comment: Good to hear that the problem is resolved. This should also implies that the missing DLL can now be found at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies and those were missing when VS was installed with minimal configuration.

Comment: Yes, it implies that DLL installs together with those .Net workloads. Just a little clarification, that the folder inside Program Files (x86) will be Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\community\common7 instead of Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7. Thanks Azaz for the continuous help.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the steps I followed in order to fix the same issue that I found with Visual Studio 2019, as I also installed it without any workload. I was also looking at a reduced installation.
The steps I did in order to fix the template error, install the following **individual components**:

- .NET 5.0 Runtime
- .Net Core 3.1 Runtime
- .NET SDK
- C# and Visual Baisc Roslyn compilers
- ClickOnce Publishing
- Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects

Hope it helps someone else. I have to point out that the comments before helped me understand the issue. But, for example, I couldn't even open the NuGet command line.